# Show 2 by 2 elements on click

Tags: jquery

I have the following container:

```
   <div id="container">
        <div id="1">1</div>
        <div id="2">2</div>
        <div id="3" style="display:none">3</div>
        <div id="4" style="display:none">4</div>
        <div id="5" style="display:none">5</div>
        <div id="6" style="display:none">6</div>
    </div>

    <div id="more_results">Show 2 more results</div>
```

How to: when I click on the show more div to display the next 2 hidden div (3 and 4).  And then if they click again show div (5 and 6)

[DEMO jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ymorin007/wpbBJ/)

Comment: What did you test ? Did you try with onClick and show/hide ?

Comment: "Make it work" is not a question. Hint: Questions usually have question marks.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to sound like that...I just didn't have any idea what method to use to accomplish the following. Sorry english is not my first language.  I will make sure it doesn't sound like that anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#more_results').click(function(){
    $('#container div:visible:last').nextAll('div').slice(0,2).show();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#more_results').on('click',function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    else
        e.stop();

    var num = 0;
    $("#container").children().each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
        if (num <= 2) {
            $(this).show();
            num++;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need all this `ID` , use a single `CLASS` instead!

***[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/GxZFS/1)***

```
var visible = 2;      // setup here initial number of visible elements

$('.element').slice(visible).hide();   // DOM READY // apply setup

$('#more_results').click(function(){
    $('.element').slice(0,visible+=2).show();  // (for the first click: get Index 0 - to 4 (excluding 4) ) and so on... we increase by 2
});
```